# import pycuda.driver returns ImportError: No module named 'Error'

Tags: python, windows, pycuda

I am on Windows 8.1, and have installed Cuda 5.5 and then installed PyCuda via building it from source. These steps seem to have worked correctly, however, when I do "import pycuda.driver" it complains that Error doesn't exist. I know that via [this](http://documen.tician.de/pycuda/driver.html) the Error class is supposed to be defined in pycuda.driver, as many other errors inherit from this. Yet it's not there.

The only place I could find an error class was in [cuda.hpp](https://github.com/inducer/pycuda/blob/fde69b0502d944a2d41e1f1b2d0b78352815d487/src/cpp/cuda.hpp). So is there simply some flag I am missing? Or some include path that I need to add?

Comment: I figured this out, it was because, when compiing, it threw an error then continued to finish the installation and installed it. And then when I tried again to build and install it just said it was successful. So if you are having the same problem, delete the build folder that is in the same directory as setup.py, and then you can build again and look for errors.

Comment: could you add a short answer to this question please? It would be good to get this question off the unanswered list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out, it was because, when compiing, it threw an error then continued to finish the installation and installed it. And then when I tried again to build and install it just said it was successful. So if you are having the same problem, delete the build folder that is in the same directory as setup.py, and then you can build again and look for errors.